# Trying to show a result regarding vectors

Tags: vectors

Suppose We have a triangle $XYZ$. Suppose three rhombuses with sides $1$ are constructed on the extensions of the sides of the triangle. Let $X X_1$, $YY_1$ and $ZZ_1$ be the diagonals of the rhombuses. I  am trying to show that $\vec{ XX_1} + \vec{ YY_1} + \vec{ ZZ_1} = \vec{0} $.

Here is the picture of the problem. Is this a correct diagram? My idea to solve the problem would be to consider triangle $Y_1 X_1 Z_1 $. Is this a right idea?

[image]

Comment: I would guess the cosine theorem could be handy if you have learned it yet. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines

Answer (score 2):

Let $$\overrightarrow{ZX}=\underline{a}, \overrightarrow{XY}=\underline{b}, \overrightarrow{YZ}=\underline{c}$$

Then, writing the unit vector parallel to $\underline{a}$ as $\underline{\hat{a}}$, and likewise for the others, we have
$$\overrightarrow{XX_1}=\underline{\hat{a}}-\underline{\hat{b}}$$
$$\overrightarrow{YY_1}=\underline{\hat{b}}-\underline{\hat{c}}$$
$$\overrightarrow{ZZ_1}=\underline{\hat{c}}-\underline{\hat{a}}$$

Adding these gives the result.

Comment: That is,  $X-X_1=(X-Y)/\|X-Y\|+(X-Z)/\|X-Z\|$ and similarly for $Y-Y_1$ and $Z-Z_1.$  Addindg them up gives $0.$

Answer (score 2):

Not a proof, perhaps, but highly suggestive:

[image]